# Wiring events to viewmodel in winrt (metro style apps)

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Behaviors are not present in metro style winrt apps.  I am trying to wire up to an event in from my view to my viewmodel.   There is a post in codeproject by [jarrey](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/319855/Attached-Command-for-Windows-8-Metro-Style-in-C?msg=4220634#xx4220634xx).  Has anyone used this before?  If you have, my question is: Can i hook up any event?  Before command binding was only available to buttons clicks.

If you have a way of wiring up events other than eventtocommand, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about events, but there is a quick implementation of behaviors for WinRT at http://winrtbehaviors.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks Filip. Your comment helped. Here is another hack that works as well.  It uses attached properties to simulated the intrinsic blend behaviors.  [article link] (http://www.silverlightplayground.org/post/2012/04/10/Metro-Wire-events-to-ICommand-with-a-%28not-so-simple%29-extension.aspx) [zip](http://www.silverlightplayground.org/assets/sources/XPG.Extensions.zip)